# Find mail on Exchange

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I would like make a programm find mail on Exchange server use GUI interface.
We can use poweshell commandlet for find mail:

```
Get-MessageTrackingLog -Server myserver -Start '01/25/2018 00:00:00' -End '01/25/2018 01:00:00' -Recipients 'user@domain'
```

This is my programm C#:

```
string connectionUri = "http://myserver/PowerShell/";
string loginPassword = textBox2.Text; // password
SecureString secpassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in loginPassword)
{
secpassword.AppendChar(c);
}
PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(textBox1.Text, secpassword); // login and password
unspace runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
PSCommand command = new PSCommand(); 
command.AddCommand("New-PSSession")
.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange")
.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", new Uri(connectionUri))
.AddParameter("Authentication", "Kerberos")
.AddParameter("Credential", credential);
powershell.Commands = command;
runspace.Open();
powershell.Runspace = runspace;
Collection<System.Management.Automation.PSObject> result = powershell.Invoke();
powershell = PowerShell.Create();
command = new PSCommand();
command.AddCommand("Invoke-Command");
command.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create("Get-MessageTrackingLog -Start '01/25/2018 00:00:00' -End '01/25/2018 01:00:00' -Recipients 'user@domain'"));
// command.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create("Get-Mailbox"));
command.AddParameter("Session", result[0]);
powershell.Commands = command;
powershell.Runspace = runspace;
var mailBoxes = powershell.Invoke();
runspace.Close();
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); // Convert result StringBuilder;
foreach (PSObject obj in mailBoxes)
{
stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
}
textBox3.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Programm connect to my server and find mail (3 message), but output result is not correct:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.Management.TransportLogSearchTasks.MessageTrackingEvent
Microsoft.Exchange.Management.TransportLogSearchTasks.MessageTrackingEvent
Microsoft.Exchange.Management.TransportLogSearchTasks.MessageTrackingEvent
```

How to make output correct?

Answer (score 0):

In .net, the default implementation of ToString() on any object simply returns the fully qualified name of the object's type. In order to print the content of the object, you must print explicitly each and every member of the object.

```
foreach (PSObject obj in mailBoxes)
{
   stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.MessageInfo);
   stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.MessageId);

   .....
}
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: You idea is good, but first need know how to receive methods and properties from exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I try connect **Microsoft.Exchange.Management.dll** from Exchange server and add next code:

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.Management.TransportLogSearchTasks;
.....
foreach (PSObject obj in mailBoxes){
  MessageTrackingEvent mte = (MessageTrackingEvent) obj;
  stringBuilder.AppendLine(mte.MessageInfo);
}
```

Error, CS0030   Cannot convert type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject'

Comment: you need to use Microsoft.PowerShell.ConvertTo() method to convert the powershell object to MessageTrackingObject. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.deserializingtypeconverter.convertto?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem

```
foreach (PSObject obj in mailBoxes)
{
stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.Properties["Sender"].Value.ToString());
}
```